# setuptools-scm: current version instead of next version

Tags: python, git, version-control, setuptools, setuptools-scm

I want to use `setuptools-scm` to control my package version. My `setup.py`:

```
setuptools.setup(
...
    use_scm_version={'write_to': 'my-package/version.py'},
...
)
```

Currently I have `v0.2` tag in my repo. I created new branch and added some commits. When I run `python setup.py --version` to create `my-package/version.py` file I get next tag `v0.3` instead of current `v0.2`:

```
$ SETUPTOOLS_SCM_DEBUG=1 python3 setup.py --version
...
cmd 'git describe --dirty --tags --long --match *.*'
out b'v0.2-1-gb13420a\n'
cmd 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'
out b'feature-version-system\n'
tag v0.2
tag 'v0.2' parsed to {'version': 'v0.2', 'prefix': '', 'suffix': ''}
version pre parse v0.2
version <Version('0.2')>
version v0.2 -> 0.2
scm version <ScmVersion 0.2 d=1 n=gb13420a d=False b=feature-version-system>
config {'version_scheme': 'guess-next-dev', 'local_scheme': 'node-and-date'}
ep ('setuptools_scm.version_scheme', 'guess-next-dev')
ep found: guess-next-dev
ep ('setuptools_scm.local_scheme', 'node-and-date')
ep found: node-and-date
version 0.3.dev1
local_version +gb13420a
0.3.dev1+gb13420a  # <- I want to see 0.2.dev1+gb13420a here
```

```
$ git tag

v0.1
v0.2
```

I think it's wrong way, because my changes I'm working for are for current release tag `v0.2`, but `setuptools_scm` said that they belong `v0.3`. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setuptools_scm` is working correctly, because it's creating a pre-release of the next version. According to [PEP440 section on pre-releases](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#pre-releases):

> The pre-release segment consists of an alphabetical identifier for the pre-release phase, along with a non-negative integer value. Pre-releases for a given release are ordered first by phase (alpha, beta, release candidate) and then by the numerical component within that phase.

They also show the example as:

```
X.YaN   # Alpha release
X.YbN   # Beta release
X.YrcN  # Release Candidate
X.Y     # Final release
```

That means that `0.3.dev1+gb13420a` is a pre-release version of `0.3`, and comes after `0.2`. `0.2.dev1+gb13420a` would mean it's a pre-release of `0.2`, and would be older than `0.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to use pre-release strategy for my software, so I moved to simple custom script `bump-version.sh`, that does same things. It would be cool if `setup_scm` version strategy can be easily customized in future.

Comment: @approximatenumber mind if you share what you have in `bump-version.sh`?

Comment: @yuenherny here you go: https://gist.github.com/approximatenumber/3e8dbddb8c261bb04b5d8e8d6ddba900

It's stupid, use it just as a reference.

Answer (score 12):

For a while now setuptools-scm offers the option to use a post-release scheme, see [setuptools_scm.version_scheme section](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/4.1.2/). Then `python setup.py --version` and `git describe --tag` will give you the same information (different formatting though). To switch to a post-release scheme, include the following line in your setup.py:

```
setup(...
      use_scm_version={'version_scheme': 'post-release'},
      ...
      )
```

Comment: Just wanted to leave a comment saying this helped me!